# Optimize `dplyr` group_by / summarize

Tags: r, optimization, dplyr, data.table

I'm looking for a trick / technique to optimize an operation like the following:

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 1e5

d <- tibble(x=sample(800, n, TRUE),
            y=sample(2000, n, TRUE) %>% as.Date(origin='1970-01-01'),
            z=sample(5, n, TRUE),
            val=runif(n))

system.time({
  y_dp <- d %>%
    group_by(x, y) %>%
    summarize(w = val[which.max(z)])
})
#     user   system  elapsed 
# 1014.918    9.760 1027.845
```

This is pretty vanilla - group by 2 variables, compute a scalar summary for each group based on another 2 variables.

`data.table` is able to handle this about 10000x more efficiently for this size of data:

```
library(data.table)
system.time({
  y_dt <- data.table(d, key=c("x", "y")) %>%
    `[`(, .(w=val[which.max(z)]), by=list(x, y)) %>%
    as_tibble()
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.109   0.003   0.112 

all.equal(y_dt, y_dp)
# TRUE
```

It presumably can achieve that by indexing (sorting, in this case) based on the keys, then iterating linearly through the structure; `dplyr` presumably has to construct separate indices into the structure for each combination `(x, y)`.

Pre-sorting by `(x, y)` doesn't help the `dplyr` case either, as it doesn't seem to "remember" that the data is sorted by what it's grouping by:

```
system.time({
  y3 <- d %>%
    arrange(x, y) %>%
    group_by(x, y) %>%
    summarize(w = val[which.max(z)])
})
#     user   system  elapsed 
# 1048.983   13.616 1070.929
```

Indeed, since the class & attributes of a tibble don't change after sorting, it seems there's no way to leverage the sorting afterwards.

Thoughts?

**EDIT**: I mistakenly wrote n <- 5e4 when the timings were actually done with n <- 1e5, I just fixed it in an edit.  Also, here are my specs:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.6_1/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.6.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.5 compiler_3.6.0   magrittr_1.5     assertthat_0.2.1
 [5] R6_2.4.0         pillar_1.4.2     glue_1.3.1       tibble_2.1.3    
 [9] crayon_1.3.4     Rcpp_1.0.1       pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.4.0     
[13] purrr_0.3.2
```

Comment: For me, it is taking just `0.209   0.022   0.231`  Change the `summarize` to `summarise`.  Also, is it possible that you loadded `plyr` library as well.  I used `set.seed(24)` for creating a reproducible example

Comment: Yeah, I get `1.22` elapsed for the first example

Comment: I also get `0.127   0.004   0.135`, using dplyr 0.8.3. Do you have an old version of dplyr??

Comment: To provide a counterpoint to the above comments, the first example took 224 seconds on my machine. MacBook Pro with Mojave. R 3.6, dplyr 0.8.2

Comment: I mistakenly wrote `n <- 5e4` when the timings were actually done with `n <- 1e5`, I just fixed it in an edit.  My time is similar to @CameronBieganek 's with `5e4`.

Comment: Now, with `1e5` it is `user  system elapsed 
  0.373   0.040   0.412` on `dplyr_0.8.3`, `R 3.6` and `macOS High Sierra 10.13.6`

Comment: Also, with `1e5` I get `0.254   0.000   0.254` R 3.5.1 and dplyr 0.8.3

Comment: I updated my `dplyr` package to `0.8.1` and now I'm getting run times more like @akrun, `0.36    0.00    0.36` using `1e5`

Comment: Aha - I installed `dplyr_0.8.3` in a private library and now I get `0.447   0.050   0.500` too.  That's quite dramatic!  Release notes for 0.8.3 say "Fixed performance regression introduced in version 0.8.2 (#4458)".

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4458 - I can write this up as an answer unless someone else wants to.

Comment: Fyi, further optimization to grouped var[which.max(x)] in data.table is planned: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/523 I guess it would work for ordered factors, not sure.

Comment: regarding first comment, confused why `summarise` vs `summarize` results would differ.

Comment: @doconnor it would make no difference, they are synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

This was caused by a regression in version 0.8.2:

> https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4458

The performance penalty is nonlinear, so in issue #4458 above it was 500x, in my example it was 10000x, and in my real data set I would probably have to wait for the heat death of the universe to measure it.

Upgrading to `dplyr` 0.8.3 fixed the problem for me:

```
> install.packages('dplyr')
# Installing package into ‘/private/tmp/lib’
# ...

n <- 1e5

d <- tibble(x=sample(800, n, TRUE),
            y=sample(2000, n, TRUE) %>% as.Date(origin='1970-01-01'),
            z=sample(5, n, TRUE),
            val=runif(n))
system.time({
  y_dp <- d %>%
    group_by(x, y) %>%
    summarize(w = val[which.max(z)])
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.447   0.050   0.500
```

Comment: ACTUALLY, I discovered it doesn't actually solve the problem on my real data set, which is a little more complicated - I'll write this up as a new bug report for `dplyr`, since on the question as I posted it here, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a perhaps more readable version of your `data.table` code.

You can pipe the `DT` with the `.` symbol from magittr. 
Another detail is you can use `.(x, y)` instead of `list(x,y)`.
Sorting isn't relevant for `data.table` in aggregations but it is for joins.

```
library(data.table)

system.time({
  y_dt <- data.table(d) %>% 
    .[, .(w = val[which.max(z)]), .(x,y)]
    as_tibble()
})
```

Another variant that removes the first pipe, therefore removing the magittr `.` as mentioned in the comments.

```
system.time({
  y_dt <- as.data.table(d)[, .(w = val[which.max(z)]), .(x,y)] %>%
    as_tibble()
})
```

Note I use as.data.table(d) instead of `setDT` as this would change `d` by reference.

Benchmark:

```
       user  system elapsed 
dplyr  2.643   0.000   2.642
DT     0.158   0.000   0.092
```

It seems`data.table` is still 28 times faster than `dplyr` in this example.

Comment: Thanks, I like that as a general technique, but `.` is starting to take so many different meanings in this example that it can get pretty confusing too.  In this case it's both the `magrittr` dot (for `.[]`) and the `data.table` dot (for `.()`), and only namespace precedence rules (or function resolution?) are preventing it from using `magrittr`'s dot inside the `.[...]` call.

Comment: As for sorting - shouldn't it be much more efficient to do grouping by a sorted variable than by an unsorted variable?

Comment: I didn't realize the `.` multiple uses but if it's inside the `DT` it represents a list. You can pass a character vector or `list()` also but if feels more verbose to me. As far as I understand sorting isn't relevant for aggregations becuase it's doing the sorting internally.

Comment: Setting a key will make joins faster, but for me this is rarely worth my (programming) time. It makes sense if you are working with a 100GB `DT`. Even if the `DT` code is not optimized, it will be fast for most purposes in 99% of the cases. At least that's my experience.